# Sending ESP8266/NodeMCU data to HTTPS webpage

Tags: php, https, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I am trying to send some data to my webpage which is secured(HTTPS) from my NodeMCU, but no data is shown on the webpage.
I checked the php side by url and also by cURL, both worked. Below is my php code that is saved in the server side.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['HTTPS']!="on")
{
 $redirect= "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 header("Location:$redirect");
}
if( $_REQUEST["d1"] ||  $_REQUEST["d2"]) 
{
echo " Data1: ". $_REQUEST['d1']. "<br />";
echo " Data2: ". $_REQUEST['d2']. "<br />";
}


$var1 = $_REQUEST['d1'];
$var2 = $_REQUEST['d2'];

$WriteMyRequest=
"<p> Data1 : " . $var1 . " </p>".
"<p> Data2 : " . $var2 . " </p><br/>";
file_put_contents('dataDisplayer.html', $WriteMyRequest, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Also my Arduino code is given below, in which I have store two random integers and tried to send to the php page which will store the data in the html page and we can see the output through that html page

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h> 
const char server[] = "shounaks.cf";
WiFiClient client;
int i;
String  postData;

const char* MY_SSID = "Redmi";
const char* MY_PWD =  "hello1234t";

void setup()
{
 i=0;
 Serial.begin(115200);
 Serial.print("Connecting to "+*MY_SSID);
 WiFi.begin(MY_SSID, MY_PWD);
 Serial.println("going into wl connect");
 while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) //not connected,  ...waiting to connect
{
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print(".");
}
Serial.println("wl connected");
Serial.println("");
Serial.println("Credentials accepted! Connected to wifi\n ");
Serial.println("");
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server..."); 
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 443)) {
  Serial.println("connected to server");
  WiFi.printDiag(Serial);
  if(i==20){
  i=0;
}
postData = "d1=" + String(i) + "&d2=" + String(analogRead(A0)) ;
i++;
 //change URL below if using your Sub-Domain
 client.println("POST /test2.php HTTP/1.1"); 
 //change URL below if using your Domain
 client.print("Host: shounaks.cf");
 client.print("\n");                 
 client.println("User-Agent: NodeMCU/1.0");
 client.print("\n");
 client.print("Content-Length: ");
 client.print(postData.length());
 client.print("\n");
 client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 client.print("\n\n");
 client.print(postData);
 client.stop(); 

 Serial.println("\n");
 Serial.println("My data string im POSTing looks like this: ");
 Serial.println(postData);
 Serial.println("And it is this many bytes: ");
 Serial.println(postData.length());       
 delay(2000);
}
}
```

Comment: Check the ESP8266 examples on how to make a HTTPS request.

Comment: Nothing is working

Comment: The examples are not able to send or receive the data, it is just showing that the server has started.

Comment: Have you tested it with `ArduinoJson ` Library.